# Fill pdf form in Android

Tags: android, pdf, pdf-generation

I am trying to develop a paid app in which part of it involve filling out an already existing pdf form. I am looking for a way to do it in Android. I have searched stack overflow and I found a library to use like iText, but it doesn't meet my needs. My requirements are the following and I hope you guys can help me out

- my app is paid app so I am looking for a library to allow me to use I for commercial purposes without limitation hidden in footnote of licenses
- I need it to work in Android as I heard libraries like iText have issue in Android (don't know why although both are Java)

So any suggestions? I just need to view and edit/fill pdfs, that's all.

Comment: Comon no answer yet? I thought I would see many answers by then

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could look at Docmosis which has a cloud service using templates and merging data to PDF.  Some devs have found it a reasonable (
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-appengine/pcz5NSz_8Co) transition from Google's soon-to-be-decomissioned Document conversion Service.